# change app background in code

Tags: image, background

I have an open source clock app that I need to modify to change the app background image based on time of day.

Because of issues with Alzheimer's my Mother getsn confused at times.  I need to have the app automatically change the background.

The person that posted the app does not support it or reply to messages so I am seeking help here.

I am not sure what code to add or where

Any help is greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: `open source` If the developer won't respond, try implementing the feature yourself. You could then push the build to your mothers phone - and even submit a pull request to the author.

Comment: Also voting to close as off topic.

Comment: My thoughts exactaly.  But I do not know how to implement this
What code and where do I need to put it to implement this feature